# Simple list from SQLite in Javascript - Not an object error

Tags: javascript, sqlite

The console is producing the following error when I try and execute my simple script to output a list of items in a database into an unordered list on a page:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'results.rows')
```

The error is thrown up in two places: 1) the callback(results); line within the queryRunner() function, and 2) the results.rows.length within the for loop.

The code in question is as follows:

```
////////////////////////////////
//  Functions
////////////////////////////////

// SQL query function
function queryRunner(input, callback) {

    // Needs to be in .transaction to work
    database.transaction(
        function( transaction ){

            // SQL Query
            transaction.executeSql(input);

        },function(err){

            console.log('errorCB: ' + err.code + '; Message: ' + err.message);

        },function( transaction, results ){

            console.log('queryRunner success!');

            // Make callback optional
            // Make sure only processes if functions included
            // i.e. ignore strings
            if(callback && typeof(callback) === 'function') { callback(results); 
            }

        }
    ); // end database.transaction

} // End queryRunner


////////////////////////////////
//  Testing
////////////////////////////////


    var databaseOptions = {
        fileName: "sqlite_WAtest",
        version: "1.0",
        displayName: "SQLite WA Test",
        maxSize: 1024
    }; // End databaseOptions



    var database = openDatabase(
        databaseOptions.fileName,
        databaseOptions.version,
        databaseOptions.displayName,
        databaseOptions.maxSize
    ); // End database

    queryRunner('DROP TABLE WORKOUTS');

    queryRunner('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WORKOUTS (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, WOdate TEXT, WOtype TEXT);');

    queryRunner('INSERT INTO WORKOUTS (WOdate, WOtype) VALUES ("Test 1","Test 2")');

    queryRunner('INSERT INTO WORKOUTS (WOdate, WOtype) VALUES ("Test 3","Test 4")');

    queryRunner('INSERT INTO WORKOUTS (WOdate, WOtype) VALUES ("Test 5","Test 6")');

    queryRunner('SELECT * FROM WORKOUTS', function(results){

        // Simple loop to output results
        for(var num=0; num<results.rows.length; num++) {

            // Get the sql data into a variable
            var row = results.rows.item(num);

            // Add it to the page
            $('#output').append('<li>This row is ID: ' + row.id + '; WOdate: ' + row.WOdate + '; and WOtype: ' + WOtype + '.</li>');

        }

    });
```

The other SQL queries are executing fine with success logged in the console and the storage browsable in the developer tools area of Safari. I think it is a breakdown of my scripting around controlling the query result into the subsequent JS for loop.

Comment: Think about it -- `length` is an array property. I suspect you want `results.rows[i].item(num)` (assuming item is a function existing on each row index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the docs over here : https://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/

The syntax of your executeSql to select/ fetch rows from the db is incorrect. It should be in the following format :

```
db.transaction(function ( tx ) {
tx.executeSql('<QUERY>', '<QUERY PARAMS>', '<SUCCESS CALLBACK>', '<ERROR CALLBACK>' );
```

Here is the interface as mentioned in the specs :

```
interface SQLTransaction {
  void executeSql(in DOMString sqlStatement, in optional ObjectArray arguments, in optional SQLStatementCallback callback, in optional SQLStatementErrorCallback errorCallback);
};
```

So you have to change your code as follows :

```
// SQL query function
function queryRunner(database, input, callback) {

    // Needs to be in .transaction to work
    database.transaction(
        function( tx ){

            // SQL Query
            tx.executeSql(input , [], function( tx, results ){

            console.log('queryRunner success!');

            // Make callback optional
            // Make sure only processes if functions included
            // i.e. ignore strings
            if(callback && typeof(callback) === 'function') { callback(results); 
            }

        },function(err){

            console.log('errorCB: ' + err.code + '; Message: ' + err.message);

        });

        }); // end database.transaction

} // End queryRunner



////////////////////////////////
//  Testing
////////////////////////////////


var databaseOptions = {
    fileName: "sqlite_WAtest",
    version: "1.0",
    displayName: "SQLite WA Test",
    maxSize: 1024
}; // End databaseOptions



var database = openDatabase(
    databaseOptions.fileName,
    databaseOptions.version,
    databaseOptions.displayName,
    databaseOptions.maxSize
); // End database

queryRunner('DROP TABLE WORKOUTS');

queryRunner('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WORKOUTS (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, WOdate TEXT, WOtype TEXT);');

queryRunner('INSERT INTO WORKOUTS (WOdate, WOtype) VALUES ("Test 1","Test 2")');

queryRunner('INSERT INTO WORKOUTS (WOdate, WOtype) VALUES ("Test 3","Test 4")');

queryRunner('INSERT INTO WORKOUTS (WOdate, WOtype) VALUES ("Test 5","Test 6")');

queryRunner('SELECT * FROM WORKOUTS', function(results){

    // Simple loop to output results
    for(var num=0; num<results.rows.length; num++) {

        // Get the sql data into a variable
        var row = results.rows.item(num);

        // Add it to the page
        $('#output').append('<li>This row is ID: ' + row.id + '; WOdate: ' + row.WOdate + '; and WOtype: ' + row.WOtype + '.</li>');

    }

});
```

Comment: That's a big help, I will re-read those pages on databases. I had the error/success on the wrong bit obviously (database.transaction) whereas it should be on executeSql. All seems to work now. Many thanks!

Comment: I have tried - unfortunately I need to up my reputation to have it made public apparently. I'll keep trying :)

Comment: That's okay. No problem :)